# Rails Devise and skip_confirmation!, how to avoid autologin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-confirmable

When I use a link from confirmation email to confirm my account, I'm redirected to login path, which is fine.
But for some users I want to skip confirmation, so I've applied a code like below in before validation collback:

```
if foo?
  self.skip_confirmation!
end
```

Problem is that when I register as that user I'm auto logged, is it any way to prevent it ? I want to skip confirmation but not autologin.

Answer (score 0):

You could try overriding devise's `RegistrationsController` and only override the `sign_up` method.  The comment for that method in the devise source says *"Signs in a user on sign up. You can overwrite this method in your own RegistrationsController"*.  You could then override it like so:

```
def sign_up(resource_name, resource)
  if !foo?    # or you could use "if !resource.confirmed?" instead.
    super  # The current implementation just calls sign_in(resource_name, resource)
  end
end
```

I haven't actually done this myself, but hopefully this helps.